# PostgreSQL filter query to Elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query like this in PG, it's very simple one to filter many range of data type. I have a query like this in PG, it's very simple one to filter many range of data type.

```
select id,
sum(1) filter (where (col1+col2+col3) > 0 and (col1+col2+col3) < 10)  as 'type_1'
from tbl
where date >= '2018-11-01'
group by id
```

Im stucked when using elasticseach to replace this query. How can I solve it with this query?

```
{  
   "size":0,
   "query":{            
   },
   "aggs":{  
      "current_data":{               
         "aggs":{  
            "id":{  
               "terms":{  
                  "field":"id",
                  "size":15
               },
               "aggs":{  
                    "type_1":{  
                       "filter" : { 
                            "bool":{ 
                                "must" : [
                                     {
                                        "range":{  
                                            "col1" + "col2" + "col3":{  // are there any equivalent to do like this?
                                               "gt":0
                                            }
                                         }
                                     }
                                ]
                            }
                       }
                    }
                 }
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a script filter like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "current_data": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id",
        "size": 15
      },
      "aggs": {
        "type_1": {
          "filter": {
            "script": {
              "script": {
                "source": "def sum = doc.col1.value + doc.col2.value + doc.col3.value; return sum > 0 && sum < 10"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: cool. this solve almost my query, but in my case: (col1+col2+col3) > 0 and (col1+col2+col3) < 10. how to add one/many "and" condition to the script?